# Generic *args type declared in subclass

Tags: python, python-typing

**What I want**

1. A base class has `__init__` method that accepts `*args`
2. Different child classes can specify different sets of `*args`
3. Each child class defines a type of accepted `*args`.
4. Type checker (`mypy`) understands this (i.e. detects cases when child class is created with incorrect set of args)

**What I have**

Piece of code that doesn't work, but illustrates what I want to do.

```
from typing import Generic, List, Tuple, TypeVar, Union

ArgsType = TypeVar("ArgsType")

class Base(Generic[ArgsType]):
    def __init__(self, *args: ArgsType):
        self.args = args

FooArgsType = Tuple[Union[int, str], ...]
BarArgsType = Tuple[List[int], ...]

class Foo(Base[FooArgsType]): pass
class Bar(Base[BarArgsType]): pass

Foo(0, "A", 1)    # OK
Foo([1], [2, 3])  # Not OK
Bar([1], [2, 3])  # OK
Bar(0, "A", 1)    # Not OK
```

Now `mypy` says `Argument 1 to "Foo" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Tuple[Union[int, str], ...]"` and I understand where this comes from, but I don't know how I should fix this.

**EDIT**

I see now that my example is not perfect because @pigrammer's answer works.
BUT I also need an option to declare more structured `*args` that specify the number of elements, e.g.

```
FooArgsType = Tuple[str, int]
BarArgsType = Tuple[int, str]
BazArgsType = Tuple[int, str, Optional[Union[int, str]]]
```

Comment: Will you ever instantiate `Base` directly? If not, I would just not define `Base.__init__` at all and define `Foo.__init__` and `Bar.__init__` specifically.

Comment: You're trying to invent [PEP646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/) - variadic generics. See this PEP for reference implementation, however at least mypy doesn't support it [yet](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12280). (Your code is almost fine, just needs `TypeVarTuple` and `Unpack` instead of regular `TypeVar`)

Comment: In response to the edit: then you don't need `*args`. It's for a variable number of arguments, not for a fixed number. You could have one parameter which is a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

When you type hint `*args` (or `**kwargs`, for that matter), you specify the type of *one* of the elements. So there's no need for the `Tuple`. Your code could then look like this:

```py
from typing import Generic, List, Tuple, TypeVar, Union

ArgsType = TypeVar("ArgsType")

class Base(Generic[ArgsType]):
    def __init__(self, *args: ArgsType):
        self.args = args

FooArgsType = Union[int, str]
BarArgsType = List[int]

class Foo(Base[FooArgsType]): pass
class Bar(Base[BarArgsType]): pass

Foo(0, "A", 1)    # OK
Foo([1], [2, 3])  # Not OK
Bar([1], [2, 3])  # OK
Bar(0, "A", 1)    # Not OK
```

Comment: Hi, this is good :) Unfortunately, not enough for me - see the **EDIT** section.